# Python library for working with 3D kinematics

Tags: python, analysis, motion, kinematics

I am new at the field of kinematics and I am looking for some Python library that will make my start with 3D kinematics easier. The only library that I found so far is **thLib**, but nothing else. I am not sure if I am using wrong keywords or is python so pour.

My goal is to use data from accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer to calculate quaternions, position in the space and analyze movement of that object. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) in that [mplot3d](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) and you can also use [robotics-toolbox-python](https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotics-toolbox-python/)